# input rangeのつまみを画像にしたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

スライダーのつまみを、cssで画像に設定したいです。

```
#filter input[type = "range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 20px; height: 20px; border:0; cursor:-webkit-grab; -webkit-appearance: none !important; background:url("image/thumb.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

としても、反映されませんでした。

[CSSフィルタことはじめ（２）Qiita](http://qiita.com/bluebird/items/49ce2d2b34ae2ac4d934)
HTMLやJavascriptは、こちらのサンプルコードを利用しています。

どうにか設定する方法はございますでしょうか？

※次のサイトのようにしますと、つまみに画像は設定されるのですが、cssフィルタとの連携がうまくできませんでした。
[Customising Cross-Browser Range Inputs with CSS and JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/custom-interactive-range-inputs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input要素自体にも`-webkit-appearance: none;`を指定する必要があるようです。

```
#filter input[type=range]{ -webkit-appearance: none; }
```

こうすると、スライダーの横線もデフォルトのスタイルが消えるので、`::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`も設定します。

```css
#filter input[type=range]{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 300px;
}

/* Chrome */
#filter input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
 height: 5px;
 background: gray;
}
#filter input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin-top: -24px;
 background: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/2.1/action/1x_web/ic_face_black_48dp.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

/* Firefox */
#filter input[type=range]::-moz-range-track{
 height: 5px;
 background: gray;
}
#filter input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb{
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 margin-top: -24px;
 background: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/2.1/action/1x_web/ic_face_black_48dp.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="filter">
 <input type="range" id="blur" value="" min="0" max="10">
</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！夜になるかと思いますが、帰宅したらさっそく試したいと思います！

Comment: mjyさま 上記のコードを試させていただいたところ、動作したのですが、自分で用意した画像にすると表示されませんでした。urlを、'./image/thumb.png' や 'image/thumb.png'にすると、つまみとして存在はしているのですが、透明なのです。

Comment: 用意した画像自体の問題なのかと思い、（つまみではなく）他のボタンで表示できている画像も指定してみましたが、同じでした・・・。

Comment: 同じコードで画像によって駄目な物があるという事でしょうか。ちょっと理由が思いつかないです。解決しない場合、コードを添えて別の質問として投稿された方が他の方の目にもとまるので、よいかと思います。この質問を編集して追加するだけでもいいかもしれません。

Comment: そうですね、同じコードでソースのurlだけ変えてみてダメでした。自分のimageディレクトリ内のpngや、google画像検索で出てきた先のurlは不可です。ご提示頂いたcdnjsにあるurlは機能します。何故なのでしょうねー…。ご親切にありがとうございます！

Comment: mjyさま ご報告させていただきます。`url() no-repeat 0 0;`ではなく、`url() no-repeat center center;`にすると表示されました！